# Access web based java application on different systems?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, web

Hi i have created a web based application using struts2,spring and ibatis. I am using Apache tomcat server to host it on my computer and using msql as datasource.
I am able to use application on my computer browser. 
But the requirement is to make this web based application to be accessible on more than one system using the browser.
Can you guys please guide me as how i can do that.As i am new to web based applications

Comment: find the ip address of your hosting system and port where the tomcat is listening to. use ip:port/applicationNameAKAContext/page to access the application. If you are trying to access it from another network, you might need to adjust the port forwarding to direct request to right system.

Comment: Hi. My web application has address as http://localhost:8080/IWantCab/
IP adress is 192.2.....(something)
Tomcat is listening to port 8080
But if i try using this to access application from another system i am nit able to access. I am using
192.2.4.3:8080/IWantCab/

Comment: Does the systems need to be connected through a LAN ?
Right now both my systems are using the same wifi network

Comment: It does not need to be connected through LAN. Can you connect to any thing in the host machine from another system like database or terminals ?

Comment: So do you want to take your web application from your personal computer and make it available to the world? Do you want to continue to run it on your own personal computer, or do you want to put it "on the Internet"?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Yeah exactly.I want to put in on the internet. I am curious to know how can i do that.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz how can i put it on internet.so that it can be accessed by a number of clients?

Comment: Get a doman name then point this machine at that domain name. This is a networking, infrastructure issue though.

Comment: The best you can really do from your home computer is to find your current public IP address (which might not be the address that "ipconfig" or "ifconfig" tells you at the command-line) and use that. You may have to enable port-forwarding on your home router to allow requests to go to your computer. Or you can rent a virtual machine by the hour from Amazon Web Services or something similar. But it's a big step to go from playing-around on your home computer to being exposed to the Internet.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz thanks for the answer. I really appreciate.Suppose i have got a domain over a internet(i have bought a new domain). And i have got a java web based application which is running on apache tomcat server. my question is 1) I want this application deployed in country 'X' to be accessible from country 'Y' over the internet. 2) how can i make use of domain to point my application.. thanks :)

Comment: @Namphibian thanks for the answer. I really appreciate.Suppose i have got a domain over a internet(i have bought a new domain). And i have got a java web based application which is running on apache tomcat server. my question is 1) I want this application deployed in country 'X' to be accessible from country 'Y' over the internet. 2) how can i make use of domain to point my application.. thanks :) –